# How can I add vaule in the Javascript String?

Tags: javascript

I want to put text which is typed by user but it's not working.
If I type "**new menu**", the result is "**$('#input_type').text()**" instead of "**new menu**".

What should I do??

Here is the code

```
    $("#plus_list").before("<a href='#' class='list-group-item'> $('#input_type').text() </a>");
```

As far as I know

```
$("#plus_list").before("<a href='#' class='list-group-item'> here what you want to show </a>");
```

is working  but I am coufusing how to put vaule not string.

Comment: `$("#plus_list").before("<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>"+ $('#input_type').text() + "</a>");` - String concatenation

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `$('#input_type').text()` is interpreted as part of the string. You need to concatenate.

```
$("#plus_list").before("<a href='#' class='list-group-item'> " + $('#input_type').text() + " </a>");
```